# UIImage imageNamed: always returns image at 1x

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, xcasset

This is my code:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self baseInit];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    if ((self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder])) {
        [self baseInit];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)baseInit {
    _selectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"SelectedStar"];
    _deselectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"DeselectedStar"];
    _rating = 6.5f;
    _editable = NO;
    _imageViews = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    _maxRating = 10;
    _minImageSize = CGSizeMake(5, 5);
    _delegate = nil;

    [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    NSLog(@"Star size: %@", NSStringFromCGSize(_selectedImage.size));
    NSLog(@"Star scale: %f", _selectedImage.scale);      
    ...
}
```

Now no matter what target OS or device simulator I use, the NSLog gives me:

```
2015-01-31 16:54:36.709 RatingViewDeveloper[6076:1679432] Star size: {21.5, 20}
2015-01-31 16:54:36.710 RatingViewDeveloper[6076:1679432] Star scale: 2.000000
```

The files in my `images.xcassets` are as follows:

- ImageSet called `DeselectedStar` with images:

  - `DeselectedStar.png`
  - `DeselectedStar@2x.png`
  - `DeselectedStar@3x.png`

and the same for an ImageSet called `SelectedStar`.

The size it returns is always the one for the standard size image, never the 2x or even 3x version, and I do not understand why, the scale is 2.0 after all. I have tried cleaning and building again, but the result is always the crappy 1x image.

Comment: The height and width of the image with always be of the 1x, 2x will automatically adjust itself, the resolution will double but height and width wont change.

Comment: Rename and set some other image as DeselectedStar@2x.png and you will see what I am talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The height and width of the image with always be of the 1x, 2x will automatically adjust itself, the resolution will double but height and width wont change.

Rename and set some other image as DeselectedStar@2x.png and you will see what I am talking about.

Comment: You are completely right, and now I also now the reason why it always looked crappy... I was drawing the selected images on top of the unselected ones, which gave them an unsightly border, I'll have to fix that but you are right.

Comment: In fact I found that using `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(clip)` makes everything have a low resolution on retina devices. Using `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(clip, NO, 2.0f)` solved that.