# CALayer getting 1x image from Images.xcassets for iPhone6 and 6Plus

Tags: ios, iphone, calayer, uiimageasset

Following `code` i am using for add `CALayer` into `UIScrollView Layer`.

```
UIImage *icon = [UIImage imageNamed:@“testImage”];
CGFloat imageWidth = icon.size.width;
CGFloat imageHeight = icon.size.height;
CGFloat y = 10;
CGFloat x = 10;
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(x, y, imageWidth, imageHeight);
CALayer *imageLayer = [CALayer layer];
imageLayer.frame = rect;
imageLayer.contents = (id)icon.CGImage;
[self.scrollView.layer addSublayer:imageLayer];
```

Thanks for help.

Please suggest if any other `idea` you have. like `example` directly get `@3x` image from `Images.xcassets`.

Comment: did you see this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28253551/uiimage-imagenamed-always-returns-image-at-1x)

Comment: Try changing the contentsScale property of the CALayer. The default value of this property is 1.0

Comment: @HuyNghia i seen that post before but i didn't added any image outside imageAssest. so how i can get 2x or 3x image.?

Answer (score 0):

Please read about the contentsScale property on the [CALayer class](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CALayer/contentsScale).

It is not automatically set to 3.0 for iPhone6 Plus.  The automatic setting only takes place for View classes.  You have to manually set it for CALayer class objects.